# Trouble with relative paths when transferring my local site to server

Tags: php, html

I was using relative paths for all of my PHP includes and locally this worked fine. I just transferred all of my files to the server and I'm getting errors for includes that point to files further up the directory. Ex:

```
include_once('../db.php');
```

is giving me:

```
Warning: include_once(../db.php) [function.include-once]: 
failed to open stream: No such file or directory in /nfs/c06/h04/mnt/188388/domains/website.com/html/includes/user_process.php on line 3
```

I'm not exactly sure what's going on. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please, tell, how you files are located relative to each other (user_process.php and db.php).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

chek if it helps

```
include_once(dirname(dirname(__FILE__)). '/db.php');
```

or

```
include_once(dirname(__DIR__). '/db.php');
```

Answer (score 0):

If file is there and access is right, It must be worked

you can try this For include_once a file in every paths of application we can do simply this

```
include_once($_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"] . "path/file")
```

or

```
<?php
if(!@file_exists('./somthing') ) {
    echo 'can not include';
} else {
   include('./something');
}
?>
```

Comment: This second solution will not solve his problem. This will only exasperate it. In this event, he will be only be hiding the error message and displaying his own. It will not locate the file for him.Also, !@file_exists could just be !file_exists, as file_exists does not return any errors, just true or false.